# Backward ARIMA forecast

Tags: arima, statsmodels

I want to try and predict previous values for random data that has properties of ARIMA process.

Problem is that I dont understand ARIMA model mathematically, so I dont know if that's even possible or allowed.

For example can I simply invert time axis and use ARIMA predictor? I would guess no.
Or can I use negative shift operator somehow?

Comment: If the process with inverted time scale still looks like ARIMA, I do not see a reason *not* to use ARIMA.